# What's the literary term for an instruction to the reader at the beginning or end of a book?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Books and other texts can have a *motto* at the beginning (or at the end), or a *dedication*. But they sometimes include a command, directive or instruction to the reader as prologue or epilogue. It could simply be “*Go and spread the word*” or “*Every time you see X, think about Y*” or “*Keep Z in your prayers*”, or something quite a bit longer.

Is there a specific word for this?

Answer (score 10):

An envoi.

Definition by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envoi): An **envoi** or **envoy** is a short stanza at the end of a poem used either to address an imagined or actual person or to comment on the preceding body of the poem.

Answer (score 7):

[Epigraph](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epigraph):

> a quotation set at the beginning of a literary work or one of its divisions to suggest its theme

[The word's Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigraph_%28literature%29) provides the following definition (as well as illustrative examples):

> In literature, an epigraph is a *phrase*, quotation, or poem that is set at the beginning of a document or component. The epigraph may serve as a preface, as a summary, as a counter-example, or to link the work to a wider literary canon, either to invite comparison or to enlist a conventional context.

Epigraphs are flexible and I expect that pithy phrases including commands, directives, and instructions will qualify.

Answer (score 4):

A *[rubric](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rubric)* is "a special instruction, heading or the like" typeset in a style that is distinct from the rest of the book - to ensure readers don't miss the message.